# In Collection does not work for me in a JPARepository query

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In Collection does not work for me in a JPARepository query

I am using Spring JPA and primefaces based environment. I created a query in my JPARepository as follows:

It works if i pass single Account object that matches some account number in the database. As soon as I add another object, the query starts returning 0

```
    Account account = new Account();
    account.setNumber("700718");
    account.setName("ENERGYAUSTRALIA NARRABRI GAS");
    accounts.add(account);

   // Un-commenting this returns 0 results
   //       Account account2 = new Account();
   //       account2.setNumber("7009");
   //       account2.setName("KRAFT FOODS LIMITED");
   //       accounts.add(account2);


    ServiceLine serviceLine = new ServiceLine();
    serviceLine.setId("AD&I");

    List<Opportunity> opps = dao.findByServiceLineAndAccountInAndOwnerContainingAndStatus(serviceLine, accounts, "Andr", "Won");
```

I get one result when the account2 is commented. Need some help

The cascaded calls look like these:
In DAO

```
  getRepository().findByServiceLineAndAccountInAndOwnerContainingAndStatus(pServiceLine, pAccounts, "%" + pOwner + "%", pStatus);
```

Call in REPOSITORY

```
  List<Opportunity> findByServiceLineAndAccountInAndOwnerContainingAndStatus(ServiceLine pServiceLine, List<Account> pAccounts, String pOwner, String pStatus);
```

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related?

Comment: and if you're really attempting to debug a JPA query, WHY do you not post the JPQL Query invoked, and what SQL is generated for it?? Without such basic information this is a guessing game

Comment: Can you post me how to log the SQL query generated by JPA repository?